# How do we convert jQuery remove class from parent in VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to convert jQuery method to VanillaJS as below.

jQuery:

```
elements.parent(".item").removeClass("item");
```

Vanilla :

```
var parent = elements.parentNode;
parent.querySelector(".item").classList.remove('item');
```

But the Vanilla script is not working as same as jQuery. Someone please suggest any better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `elements` is plural, I'm assuming it's a collection, so use `.forEach()`. *(This needs to be patched in legacy browsers unless `elements` is an actual `Array`)*

```
elements.forEach(function(el) {
  el.parentNode.classList.remove("item");
});
```

Note that you do not need to filter down to just the `.item` elements. If it doesn't have the class, it'll be a no-op.

Also note that `.querySelector` only searches for descendants. If you did need to filter on the class for other reasons, you'd use `.matches`.

```
elements.forEach(function(el) {
  var par = el.parentNode;
  if (par.matches(".item")) {
    // Do work with the `.item` element
    par.classList.remove("item");
  }
});
```

---

If there could be multiple ancestors with the `.item` class, then traverse those ancestors in a nested loop.

```
elements.forEach(function(el) {
  var par = el.parentNode;
  do {
    if (par.matches(".item")) {
      // Do work with the `.item` element
      par.classList.remove("item");
    }
  } while((par = par.parentNode));
});
```

---

You could make a helper function if you're doing this frequently.

```
function ancestors(el, filter) {
  var res = [];
  var par = el.parentNode;
  do {
    if (!filter || par.matches(filter)) {
      res.push(par);
    }
  } while((par = par.parentNode));

  return res;
}
```

So then it's like this.

```
elements.forEach(function(el) {
  ancestors(el, ".item")
    .forEach(function(par) { par.classList.remove(".item"); });
});
```

Comment: Something wrong in your sample: test for `el.matches(".item"))` and removal of class `.item` from its *parent*

Comment: Thanks @spanky for your solution. What if we change `parents(".item")`, instead of using `parent(".item")` ? Can't use  `parentNode` and any better way to do that ?

Comment: The you'd need a loop inside the current loop to iterate up the `.parentNode`s. I'll update with an example.

Comment: Thanks for the great help @spanky :) Can you please update it in ES5 ?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, I'll change the examples to ES5 syntax, though I'd recommend modern syntax with a transpiler.

Comment: @user8431453: Right, but that's what a transpiler is for. It'll convert your code to ES5 so it'll run in legacy browsers. Then in the future when you drop support for those browsers, you can just stop transpiling and serve the modern code instead. Either way, just letting you know the options.